# JAR with multiple main() -- how to start second application from first?

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

I have joined two seperate JARs, which shared large amounts of code, into a single JAR. No problem so far, since you can have more than one `static void main()` in a JAR.

The main application is called directly:

```
java -jar myjar.jar arg1 arg2
```

The other application requires explicit invocation of its alternative `main()`:

```
java -classpath myjar.jar alternative.main arg1
```

Not much of a problem either.

However, now I have to call the *alternative* application from *within* the main one.

I could do this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "java -classpath myjar.jar alternative.main arg1" );
```

But this strikes me as lacking some finesse. Is there some more ellegant / efficient way to start the second, alternative `main()`?

Comment: If it is in one jar anyways, can't you simply **call** the other `main` method? Or do you require separate operating system processes / JVMs?

Comment: 1) If falling back to using a `Process`. Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces. 2) This really smells of bad design, unless the first app. is an 'app. suite launch toolbar'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Bad design it is, it should have been a single application to begin with. Unfortunately sometimes you have to live with sub-par designs because a full-scale refactoring doesn't fit into the budget...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's okay for both main apps to run in the same JVM, and the call to be synchronous, then this should work.

```
String[] args = { "arg1" };
alternative.main.main(args);
```

If the call should not be synchronous, but can be a different thread within the same JVM, then you can create a new thread which calls the alternative `main` method.

If it must be a separate process/JVM, then what you are doing works well enough. Alternatively, you could use `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
alternative.main.main(new String[]{arg1});
```

Comment: I have, and it failed, but as it turned out for a completely unrelated reason. ;-)